# How to convert a decimal number into fraction?

Tags: python, decimal, fractions

I was wondering how to convert a decimal into a fraction in its lowest form in Python.

For example:

```
0.25  -> 1/4
0.5   -> 1/2
1.25  -> 5/4
3     -> 3/1
```

Comment: Convert 0.25 to 25/100, then figure out largest common factor?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use [`float.as_integer_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio):

   ```
   >>> (0.25).as_integer_ratio()
   (1, 4)
   ```

   (as of Python 3.6, you can [do the same with a `decimal.Decimal()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.as_integer_ratio).)
2. Use the [`fractions.Fraction()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction):

   ```
   >>> from fractions import Fraction
   >>> Fraction(0.25)
   Fraction(1, 4)
   ```

The latter has a very helpful `str()` conversion:

```
>>> str(Fraction(0.25))
'1/4'
>>> print Fraction(0.25)
1/4
```

Because floating point values can be imprecise, you can end up with 'weird' fractions; limit the denominator to 'simplify' the fraction somewhat, with [`Fraction.limit_denominator()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator):

```
>>> Fraction(0.185)
Fraction(3332663724254167, 18014398509481984)
>>> Fraction(0.185).limit_denominator()
Fraction(37, 200)
```

If you are using Python 2.6 still, then `Fraction()` doesn't yet support passing in a `float` directly, but you *can* combine the two techniques above into:

```
Fraction(*0.25.as_integer_ratio())
```

Or you can just use the [`Fraction.from_float()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.from_float):

```
Fraction.from_float(0.25)
```

which essentially does the same thing, e.g. take the integer ratio tuple and pass that in as two separate arguments.

And a small demo with your sample values:

```
>>> for f in (0.25, 0.5, 1.25, 3.0):
...     print f.as_integer_ratio()
...     print repr(Fraction(f)), Fraction(f)
... 
(1, 4)
Fraction(1, 4) 1/4
(1, 2)
Fraction(1, 2) 1/2
(5, 4)
Fraction(5, 4) 5/4
(3, 1)
Fraction(3, 1) 3
```

Both the `fractions` module and the `float.as_integer_ratio()` method are new in Python 2.6.

Comment: Thanks! Options 1 works, but option 2 (Fraction(0.25)) gives me the error: "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index". Can you tell me why?

Comment: @user2370460: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python 2.6.1, on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: @user2370460: Ah, yes, only version 2.7 and up support passing in a float or decimal type; use `Fraction(*(0.25).as_integer_ratio())` instead in that case.

Comment: Note, both the `fractions` module and `float.as_integer_ratio` were added in Python 2.6. If you're running an older version of Python these will not be available.

Comment: @user2370460: I totally managed to miss the available `Fraction.from_float()` class method, much clearer. `Fraction.from_float(0.25)`.

Comment: How usable is `as_integer_ratio` in practice? To me it seems to be limited to values with powers of 2 in the denominator.

Comment: @Wolf not sure what tests you did but `as_integer_ratio()` is reliable and exact. Note that floating point numbers are built up from binary fractions, and binary fractions by definition have 1 as the numerator and a power of two as the denominator. It would therefor be quite normal for their integer ratio to reflect that.

Comment: @Wolf I don’t find the results surprising. If you feel the docs should be updated you’ll have to ask the Python team.

Answer (score 15):

```
from fractions import Fraction

print(Fraction(0.25))
print(Fraction(0.5))
print(Fraction(1.25))
print(Fraction(3))

#1/4
#1/2
#5/4
#3
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me:    "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index". Can you tell me why?

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'd like to add: the one-argument constructor works well for some numbers, but not others. For instance, `Fraction(.2)` becomes `Fraction(3602879701896397, 18014398509481984)`. It might be better to use the two-argument constructor, ex. `Fraction(2,10)`

Comment: @Kevin: that's because .2 cannot be accurately represented by a float. See my answer for a workaround; limit the denominator and you can bring back it back to 2/10 in a jiffy.

Answer (score 13):

To expand upon Martijn Pieters excellent answer with an additional option due to the imprecision inherent with more complex floats. For example:

```
>>> f = 0.8857097
>>> f.as_integer_ratio()
(1994440937439217, 2251799813685248)          # mathematically wrong
>>> Fraction(f)
Fraction(1994440937439217, 2251799813685248)  # same result but in a class
>>> Fraction(f).limit_denominator()
Fraction(871913, 984423)                      # still imprecise
```

The mathematical result desired was `8857097/10000000` which can be achieved by casting to a string and then manipulating it.

**Edited Response**

I found a much simpler way to resolve the accuracy issue.

```
>>> Fraction(str(f))
Fraction(8857097, 10000000)
```

Casting as to a string also allows for accurate Decimal instances

```
>>> Decimal(f).as_integer_ratio()
(1994440937439217, 2251799813685248)
>>> Decimal(str(f)).as_integer_ratio()
(8857097, 10000000)
```

**Original Response**

```
def float_to_ratio(flt):
    if int(flt) == flt:        # to prevent 3.0 -> 30/10
        return int(flt), 1
    flt_str = str(flt)
    flt_split = flt_str.split('.')
    numerator = int(''.join(flt_split))
    denominator = 10 ** len(flt_split[1])
    return numerator, denominator
```

Now let's test it:

```
>>> float_to_ratio(f)
(8857097, 10000000)      # mathematically correct
```

I will note that this kind of fraction precision is not optimized and will usually not be needed, but for completeness it is here. This function doesn't simplify the fraction, but you can do additional processing to reduce it:

```
>>> n = 0.5
>>> float_to_ratio(n)
(5, 10)
>>> Fraction(*float_to_ratio(n))
Fraction(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to print a *proper fraction*, this little recipe should do:

```
from fractions import Fraction    

def dec_to_proper_frac(dec):
    sign = "-" if dec < 0 else ""
    frac = Fraction(abs(dec))
    return (f"{sign}{frac.numerator // frac.denominator} "
            f"{frac.numerator % frac.denominator}/{frac.denominator}")
```

This will print as follows:

```
>>> dec_to_proper_frac(3.75)
>>> "3 3/4"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it simple and properly.

**By using Fraction:**

```
from fractions import Fraction
decimals = [0.25, 0.5, 1.25, 3, 0.6, 0.84]

for d in decimals:
    print(Fraction(str(d))) #Cast as string for proper fraction
```

**By using Decimal:**

```
from  decimal import Decimal
decimals = [0.25, 0.5, 1.25, 3, 0.6, 0.84]

for d in decimals:
    d = Decimal(str(d)) #Cast as string for proper fraction
    nominator,denominator = d.as_integer_ratio()
    if denominator==1:
        print(a)
    else:
        print(nominator,denominator, sep="/")
```

**Output:**

```
1/4
1/2
5/4
3
3/5
21/25
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to use `as_integer_ratio()` like this.

```js
b = 0.125

b.as_integer_ratio()

# Output as Tuple(1, 8).Numerator as 1 & Denominator as 8
```