# Converting decimals to fractions

Tags: python, fractions

I just wanted to convert a decimal to fractions in Python. I found some answers here on stackoverflow.

[How to convert a decimal number into fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344185/python-convert-decimal-into-fraction)

I tried both the methods but they didn't worked for 1.4 as input, though they worked for 0.25

- Using standard Library: fractions
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwojz.png
- The other way
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdDeq.png

Comment: Not all real values can be represented in floating point. Evaluating `(1.4).as_integer_fraction()` will give you `(3152519739159347, 2251799813685248)`, which is [pretty close to 1.4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3152519739159347+%2F+2251799813685248). If you want 100 percent precision then you'll have to avoid floats altogether and use decimals from the start.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your integer into a string. Let us call this `alpha`
2. Find the `length` of `alpha`
3. Create two empty string: `beta` and `gamma`
4. Init a `for-loop` from 0 to `length`
5. Add all elements in `alpha` to `beta` until a `.` is found

   ```
   If a decimal is not found or only 0 (or any amounts of zeros), then your number is over `alpha` over 1.
   If a decimal is found, start adding the elements to `gamma`
   ```
6. Convert `gamma` back into an `int` and use the function you found previously.
7. Convert `beta` back into an `int` and multiply this by `gamma`.
8. Add this to the tuple from the function you posted.

**All done!**

I wrote this in [python](/questions/tagged/python) to quickly demonstrate an implementation.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS IS NOT DONE AS WE ARE NOT SIMPLIFYING THE FRACTION. THIS ALSO DOES NOT USE THE PATTERN THAT I LISTED ABOVE BECAUSE OF REASONS *paul manta* DECLARED.**

Here ya go,

```
  def findFraction(string):
        from math import pow
        length      = len(string)
        c           = '{a}/{b}'.format(a=string, b=int(pow(10,length)))
        print(c)
        return c

  def finishFraction(addToNumerator, currentFraction):
        temp        = ''
        temp2       = ''
        slashFlag   = False
        for i in range(0,len(currentFraction)):
              if currentFraction[i]=='/':
                    slashFlag = True
              elif slashFlag==True:
                    temp2 =temp2+currentFraction[i]
              else:
                    temp  = temp+currentFraction[i]
        numerator   = int(temp)+(int(addToNumerator)*int(temp2))
        fraction    = str(numerator)+'/'+str(temp2)
        return fraction

  def fractionForm(number):
        alpha       = str(number)
        length      = len(alpha)
        beta        = ''
        gamma       = ''
        dotFlag     = False
        for i in range(0, length):
              if alpha[i]=='.':
                    if dotFlag==True:
                          print("SHOULD NOT HAVE TWO DECIMALS IN NUMBER")
                          assert(False)
                    dotFlag=True
              elif dotFlag==False:
                    beta=beta+alpha[i]
              else:
                    gamma=gamma+alpha[i]
        if gamma=='':
              print('{a}/{b}'.format(a=int(beta),b=1))
              return (int(beta),1)
        else:
              fraction    = findFraction(gamma)
              fraction    = finishFraction(beta,fraction)
              print(fraction)
              return fraction

  def test():
        woooo = fractionForm(1.25)
        woohoo= fractionForm(99.999)

  dtest()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(a):
    d = 0
    s = str(a)

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == '.':
            d = len(s) - (i+1)
            break

    b = 10**d
    a*= b
    a = int(a)
    c = 1

    for j in range(2, min(a,b)+1):
        if a%j == 0 and b%j == 0:
            c = j

    a//= c
    b//= c

    print(a,'/',b)

f(float(input()))
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.