# Get the most simplified fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I'm writing a program that uses the `Fractions` module. I want to get the most simplified fraction of a float. When I try it with numbers like `0.5`, it works correctly:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> str(fractions.Fraction(0.5))
'1/2'
```

But when I try it with `0.55` or `0.1` it displays fractions with very high numerator and denominator, instead of `11/20` and `1/10`.

```
>>> str(fractions.Fraction(0.1))
'3602879701896397/36028797018963968'
>>> str(fractions.Fraction(0.55))
'2476979795053773/4503599627370496'
```

What can I do to be sure that the script will always display the most simplified fraction? Is there any way to do it with `Fractions` module or another module, or I have to write the function myself?

Comment: When you pass `0.55` you are passing in a float, so it is already an inexact representation before the `Fraction` receives the value

Comment: The crux is that simple decimal fractions like e.g. 0.1 are often periodic fractions in the dual system. The floating point numbers used in the computer make it even more worse. Recommended reading: [Floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: If you pass a string like `Fraction('0.1')` it will work.

Comment: @khelwood Do you know what causes the giant numbers to appear for `0.1`? Is there some deterministic rule for this?

Comment: @roganjosh Only that the float will try and store the closest value to 0.1 that fits its binary representation.

Comment: Ok, so I'll pass the number as a string. This solves the problem

Comment: It's not dulicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344185/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-into-fraction. It doesn't explain why I have to pass the number as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `0.55` you are passing in a float, so it is already an inexact representation before the `Fraction` receives the value.

Alternatively, if you pass a string instead, you can get the exact value you want:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction('0.55')
Fraction(11, 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fractions.Fraction(0.1).limit_denominator()
```

See the results:

```
In [77]: str(fractions.Fraction(0.55).limit_denominator())
Out[77]: '11/20'

In [78]: str(fractions.Fraction(0.1).limit_denominator())
Out[78]: '1/10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `decimal` module example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Fraction(Decimal('0.55'))
>>> Fraction(11, 20)
>>> str(Fraction(11, 20))
>>> '11/20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as string to get the simplified fraction:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction('0.1')
Fraction(1, 10)
>>> str(fractions.Fraction('0.1'))
'1/10'
```