# Make quotient an integer if the number divides perfectly

Tags: python, division

If perfect division occurs between two numbers, I want the result to be converted into an integer but if perfect division does not occur between the two numbers, then no change should be made.
For example, `6/2` gives the result `3.0`. Since this is perfect division, the `3.0` should be converted into `3`. On the other hand if I have `14/4`, which gives result `3.5`, it should stay as it is since perfect division has not occurred.

Here by perfect division I mean `a` divided by `b` yields an integer

Comment: You already have some solutions, but there are also some built-in functions which are described here, which might be useful: [How to convert a decimal number into fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344185/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-into-fraction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function checks if there is a remainder if you divide. If so, it's not an integer.

```
def divide_and_conquer(a, b):
    return a / b if a % b else a // b
```

Comment: If speed is an issue: `a//b` is more efficient than `int(a/b)`

Comment: @Feodoran, added to the answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step solution on how you can achieve that

```
# the numbers
num = 34
divisor = 17

# do the division
modula = num//divisor # modulus
quotient = num/divisor # normal division

# check if division is perfect
if modula  == quotient :
   result = int(quotient)
else:
   result = quotient
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use // to divide integers, and get an integer result. You can also use % to determine if two numbers divide perfectly (% returns the remainder, which is always zero if and only if the two numbers divide perfectly). To accomplish what you're asking, simply:

```
a = 6
b = 2
if a % b == 0:
  result = a // b
else:
  result = a / b
```

That said, you could also simply run the standard division and convert the result to an integer as well...

```
result = a / b
if result % 1 == 0:
  result = int(result)
```

However, in both of these cases, you might want to examine the broader context of what you're coding, because it can create real problems down the line if a variable is sometimes one data type, and other times a different data type - it might be best to leave the value as a float in every case until such time that you need for it to become an integer.

Note: Using '//' on two integers which do not divide perfectly will still result in an integer, as python will simply ignore the remainder. 6 // 4 = 1, 15 // 2 = 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `//` division to get an `int`:

```
def divide(a, b):
    return a / b if a % b else a//b

divide(2, 5)   # 0.4 (float)
divide(10, 5)  # 2 (int)
```