# Return a result of a formula as a fraction (when possible) instead of its numeric value (i.e. 5/6 instead of 0.8333333333333334)

Tags: python

I am using Python in a Jupyter lab enviroment.

If I define this function:

```
def f(n): 
    return ((n - 1) + 1/2) / n
```

when I execute this:

```
f(3)
```

the function returns `0.8333333333333334`

Instead I'd rather get `5/6` as a result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a decimal number into fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344185/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-into-fraction)

Comment: It might be worth understanding that ``1/2`` (and similar) is not a fraction as in *the type*, but a fraction as in *the operation*. It literally means evaluating "divide 1 by 2".

Comment: When you say you would "rather get ``5/6`` as a result", what do you assume is (or desire as) the type of ``5/6``? Naively, ``5/6`` *is* 0.8333333333333334 in Python.

Comment: I was thinking to something similar to this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28n+-+1%29+%2B+1%2F2%29+%2F+n+with+n+%3D+3

Comment: You might be looking for symbolic computation, e.g. as provided by ``sympy``.

Comment: sympy is actually what I used at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) package:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def f(n): 
  return Fraction(((n - 1) + Fraction(1, 2)), n)

print(f(3))
```

will print

```
5/6
```

Comment: You might get a massive fraction from time to time, so you can use the method .limit_denominator() to avoid this

Comment: @en_lorithai Since I don't use float division it would only generate a massive denominator if `n` is massive too, which is expected.

Comment: Float division is default in python 3 which more and more people are using. should be mentioned.

Comment: @en_lorithai There are no divisions in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk

I also found this other way:

     from sympy import symbols, sympify

     n = symbols('n')
     f = sympify("((n - 1) + 1/2) / n")
     print(f.subs(n, 3))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fractions` module.

```
from fractions import Fraction 

fraction = Fraction(0.8333333333333334).limit_denominator(10)
```