# Getting the shutter speed from exif data using python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using `from PIL import Image, ExifTags` to access exif data of images.

`exif.get('ExposureTime')` returns `0.008` but I would like it expressed as `1/125`. I can see this value under the `ExposureTime` dict. But how do I access it?

Comment: post some code... perhaps how you can 'see it'?  if it's just a dict it should be pretty easy to get it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344185/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-into-fraction) help?

Comment: 0.008 are the **amount in seconds** that the exposure took, which gives 1/125 **fractions of a second**. Basically you want convert seconds in fractions of a second.

Comment: In Pycharm I see `ExposureTime` dict with a value of `0.008` yes the decimal of 1/125. Within the dict, labelled `real` is the value 1/125. For different images the value will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the reciprocal `1/x`. So `1/0.008 = 125`. Since the shutter speed is stored as a float you just need to format it as a string `"1/"+str(1/0.008)` will result in `1/125`