# How to find the lowest number to multiply all elements of a list with n numbers for all the elements to become integers?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find the lowest number that when multiplied with all elements of a list gives an integer, for example: [2.25, 3.5] - the result would be 4 because it turns the list into [9, 14] and it is the lowest number that could do that.

I tried solving it with weird math.lcm, 1/i%1, math.gcd and I dont think it will help if I show what I tried because it is completely wrong.

Comment: Does this help get you started; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344185/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-into-fraction

Comment: Is this about the code, or more about the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

First save the denominators in a list:
Multiply each item with 10^after_point_digits_count then simplify it by the denominator as much as possible.

```
denominators = []
for item in my_list:
    splitted_item = str(item).split('.')
    int_part = splitted_item[0]
    try:
        fraction_part = splitted_item[1]
    except:
        fraction_part = ""
    
    d = 10**len(fraction_part)
    int_item = int(d * item)
    
    while int_item % 2 == 0 and d % 2 == 0:
        int_item /= 2
        d /= 2
    while int_item % 5 == 0 and d % 5 == 0:
        int_item /= 5
        d /= 5
    
    denominators.append(int(d))
```

Find the LCM (Least common multiple):

```
from math import gcd as get_gcd

lcm = 1
for i in denominators:
    lcm = lcm*i//get_gcd(lcm, i)
```

Then multiply all list members with the LCM:

```
my_new_list = [item*gcd for item in my_list]
```

p.n 1:
using `from fractions import Fraction` doesn't get the best answer always. for example `Fraction(1.8)` is not 18/10 or 9/5, It is `8106479329266893 / 4503599627370496`. So creating the algorithm always gives the best answer.
p.n 2:
The first code block could be implemented with higher performance. Save and mul and div large numbers takes more time so we can decrease the operations like this:

```
denominators = []
for item in my_list:
    splitted_item = str(item).split('.')
    int_part = splitted_item[0]
    try:
        fraction_part = splitted_item[1]
    except:
        fraction_part = ""
    
    # d[0]: power of factor 2
    # d[1]: power of factor 5
    d = [len(fraction_part), len(fraction_part)]
    str_int_item = ''.join(splitted_item)
    int_item = int(str_int_item)
    
    while d[0] and str_int_item[-1] in ['0','2','4','6','8']:
        d[0] -= 1
        int_item /= 2
        str_int_item = str(int_item)
    while d[1] and str_int_item[-1] in ['0','5']:
        d[1] -= 1
        int_item /= 5
        str_int_item = str(int_item)

    min_d_amount = 2**d[0] * 5**d[1]
    denominators.append(min_d_amount)
```

Comment: Nice solution! Would `fractions.Fraction(decimal.Decimal(str(1.8)))` solve the precision problem?

Comment: Probabely NO! because there is some numbers which the answer will not be exact even using `decimal` (for example `2365688911.46516513551`). I don't know how the libraries work but they are not exact in all test cases.